How many satisfiable assignments does the following compound statement have?
I want to count satisfiable assignments to the following compound proposition:
$((p→q)∧(¬q∨r)∧(¬s→¬r))→(¬p∨s)$
Is there any particular formula to calculate this? For small compound proposition we can do it manually, but the given compound proposition is huge. Any hint or suggestion would be of great help.

If such a formula exists, then it would immediately indicate whether a given propositional formula is a tautology, and whether it is a contradiction.

@ryang I don’t see why that is a problem. Propositional logic is decidable.

@DavidGao My point was not that such a formula cannot exist. However: even if an algorithm—as opposed to a simple formula—exists for general propositional formulae—as opposed to those in normal forms—it would be very hard to determine.

@ryang I agree. I suppose depending on how a “simple formula” is defined, it might even be possible to prove it cannot exist based on computational complexity reasons.

@TankutBeygu That question seems to me like it is completely irrelevant and nothing similar (except the broad topic) to the OP's question.

@DavidGao then, I retract my comment. As I can understand, the OP asks for a general heuristic aid, rather than a solution to a specific formula. But that would call for techniques to simplify Boolean expressions.

@TankutBeygu Yeah, I suppose the OP's question does seem to indicate they want a more general result than just solving this specific question. I don't think such things really exist, though. Both my answer to this question and the answer you previously linked to only address specific formulae.

Though the question actually refers to an NP-hard problem, there are techniques to tackle it significantly. However, they seem entirely out of context.

It might be easier, in this case, to count truth assignments that do not satisfy the given proposition. Indeed,
$$\begin{split}
&((p \to q) \wedge (\neg q \vee r) \wedge (\neg s \to \neg r)) \to (\neg p \vee s) = F\\
\Leftrightarrow &(p \to q) \wedge (\neg q \vee r) \wedge (\neg s \to \neg r) = T \text{ and } \neg p \vee s = F\\
\Leftrightarrow &p \to q = T \text{ and } \neg q \vee r = T \text{ and } \neg s \to \neg r = T \text{ and } \neg p = F \text{ and } s = F\\
\Leftrightarrow &(p = F \text{ or } q = T) \text{ and }(\neg q = T \text{ or } r = T) \text{ and } (\neg s = F \text{ or } \neg r = T) \text{ and } p = T \text{ and } s = F\\
\Leftrightarrow &q = T \text{ and } r = T \text{ and } \neg s = F \text{ and } p = T \text{ and } s = F\\
\Leftrightarrow &\bot
\end{split}$$
That is, there are no truth assignments that do not satisfy the given proposition, or, equivalently, all $2^4 = 16$ truth assignments satisfy the given proposition.

Perhaps more intuitively, the LHS (to the left of $\to$) is $p \to q$; and $\neg q \vee r$, which is equivalent to $q \to r$; and $\neg s \to \neg r$, which, using contrapositive, is equivalent to $r \to s$. Composing the three material implications shows the LHS implies $p \to s$, which is equivalent to $\neg p \vee s$, i.e., the RHS (to the right of $\to$). Thus, the proposition is a tautology - it is always true.

I'll take a crack at this. The first thing to know is that, for classical propositional logic, the number of combinations of truth-value assignments is $2^n$, where $n$ denotes the number of atomic formulae.
When the main operator is a conditional, as it is in $((p \rightarrow q) \wedge (\neg q \vee r) \wedge (\neg s \rightarrow \neg r)) \rightarrow (\neg p \vee s)$, there are exactly 2 situations in which the proposition is satisfiable:

The consequent is true.
The antecedent is false.

Let's start with 1: $\neg p \vee s$. Obviously, its truth-function yields $T$ when $s$ yields $T$ or $p$ yields $F$. There are exactly 12 truth-table rows in which one of those is the case. We know this because there's always a $3/4$ return of $T$ for two distinct literals in truth-table (base case, $TTFF \vee TFTF$), and $3/4 \times 16 = 48/4 = 12$.
Let's move on to 2: $(p \rightarrow q) \wedge (\neg q \vee r) \wedge (\neg s \rightarrow \neg r)$. Of the remaining 4 rows, only those whose antecedent is false would be there. However, no row among them may also permit $p$ assigned $F$ or $s$ assigned $T$. We must therefore switch both to their opposite values and see if there are any possible combinations in which the entire conjunct is false. This is much more manageable, now, as a direct table, since $p$ must be locked to $T$ and $s$ must me locked to $F$ for this test, and we solve for $q$ and $r$.

$(p \rightarrow q) \wedge (\neg q \vee r) \wedge (\neg s \rightarrow \neg r)$
$(T \rightarrow q) \wedge (\neg q \vee r) \wedge (\neg F \rightarrow \neg r)$
$q \wedge (\neg q \vee r) \wedge (T \rightarrow \neg r)$
$q \wedge (\neg q \vee r) \wedge \neg r$
$q$ as $F$ clearly works, so that's 2 down (half of our remaining 4), and let's move to the remaining 2 by assuming $q$ is $T$.
$T \wedge (\neg T \vee r) \wedge \neg r$
$(F \vee r) \wedge \neg r$
$r \wedge \neg r$
$r$ can be either $T$ or $F$ and the antecedent would still yield $F$. Those were the remaining 2 combinations.

So, it's a classical tautology: $12 + 2 + 2 = 16 = 2^4$.
